# How to run php/html code after someone has paid in paypal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, paypal

Basically what I am trying to do is, make is to that if and only if someone goes through with the payment and pays it will write certain data to an SQL server. I understand i could just redirect them to a page that runs the code but the issue is they could just refresh infinitely. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't run any code on PayPal.  You will just need to put your functionality into whatever the payment success return page is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Paypal documentation, but when I did this last, the interface had a place where you can put your receiving URL.  There you can test for $_POST["RESPMSG"] == "Approved"

Comment: So what you are saying is to, run SQL code from that text box? or go to a page with this in it? I'm confused.

Comment: What text box?  You have a destination page set up in Paypal, you check the response received via POST, and if "Approved" you run your SQL insert and then redirect to a thank you page.